# Generate Typescript from OpenApi 3. Mark property as deprecated?

Tags: typescript, openapi, openapi-generator

I have an OpenApi 3 - JSON definition file from which I'd like to generate my TS - Api and Models code.

**Problem: the statusCode property does not get marked as deprecated.**

Definition file (def.json) has

```
{
  "x-generator": "NSwag v13.10.6.0 (NJsonSchema v10.3.8.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))",
  "openapi": "3.0.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "PortalService",
    "version": "v1.0"
  },
 "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Invoice": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "required": [
              "documentType",
              "userCreationDate",
              "dueDate",
              "statusCode",
              "creationTime"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string",
                "nullable": true
              },
              ...
              "statusCode": {
                "deprecated": true, <= Seems fine ??
                "allOf": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/InvoiceStatusCode"
                  }
                ]
              },
              ...
    
            }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I miss it in the generated output file (Invoice.ts)

```
export interface Invoice {
...
    /**
     * 
     * @type {InvoiceStatusCode}
     * @memberof Invoice

     => missing @deprecated <=
     */
    statusCode: InvoiceStatusCode;
...
}
```

I am using openapi-generator-cli generate -i swagger.json -g typescript-fetch (V.5.0.0 I believe)
and my swagger-config.json reads:

```
{
  "npmName": "my_api",
  "npmVersion": "0.1.0",
  "supportsES6": true,
  "modelPropertyNaming": "camelCase",
  "useSingleRequestParameter": false,
  "enumPropertyNaming": "PascalCase",
  "typescriptThreePlus": true
}
```

Any ideas? :o

Comment: You ever solve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet :/

Answer (score 1):

Solved it for my case int that I generated the swagger.json file differently:
Adding

```
IgnoreObsoleteProperties = true,
```

to the SchemaSettings in ASP.NET together with the latest Openapi-generator-cli (5.2.7 as of writing), solves the issue for me. Maybe this helps sb else. Cheers